# ASP.NET WEb Forms application does not enter Page_Load after redirection from login

Tags: asp.net, redirect, pageload

The situation here is a little bit odd. I have two pages **downloads.aspx** and **login.aspx**.

In **downloads.aspx** if an user wants to download a private file s/he is required to **register** or **login**.

The login link, from **downloads.aspx**, is as follows:

```
<a href="login.aspx?ref=~/downloads.aspx">
```

If I run the page the login is correctly performed and redirects to **download.aspx**. Since I wanted to debug some behavior in the **login.aspx** page I put some watches in the `Page_Load` event handler but...it never goes there! The same applies for the other method `Login()` within **login.aspx** code behind.

So I thought, since it performs the redirect, it should go again in the `Page_Load` event handler of **downloads.aspx** but...also there the same problem! Everything is perfect at runtime but, in debug mode when redirects from **login.aspx**, it does not enter **downloads.aspx**!!! This bothers me since after the redirect I want to perform some computation before displaying again the **downloads.aspx** page.

I also tried to set `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)` before the redirects but no luck! Anybody knows what can be the cause?

Comment: Also make sure that the OutputCache directive is not set to cache on the server in either of the .aspx files.  Other than that, this should work fine.  Also are you sure you are running in debug mode?  Is debug set to true in the web.config?  If you put a break point in the login page is it hit?  Not trying to insult your intelligence, but we all have brain farts sometimes.

Comment: @swannee, how dare you insult my intelligence? :-) Just kidding, SO is a forum where people ask for help so any suggestion is taken as a nice gift. The compilation debug is set to true. However I am currently running it in Visual Studio, therefore where can I set the OutputCache directive? thanks

Comment: If the OutputCache directive was set, it would be at the top of the aspx file by the page directive.  How about posting some code?  If it's working as expected I'm sure the events are wired correctly.  It's just something with the debug.  Are you able to hit any breadkpoints or is it just after the redirect that you have issues?

Comment: @swannee, there is no directive. The debug works good in other breakpoints. I just noticed that if I start the project from the login page, the breakpoints are hit, but not if I access from downloads. Sometimes I got an erro in the breakpoint that cannot be hit bcause of symbols missing...

Comment: Last ditch idea:  Try:  Clean the solution, rebuild the solution, delete the temporary files here (path may not be exact but you will have a similar one): C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        // clear the users cache so that they'll get current data.
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("login.aspx?ref=~/downloads.aspx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was due to multiple IIS applications. A redirect caused the url to change enough that execution was being handled by the second application. The resolution was to remove the second application from IIS.

You can set breakpoints in Global.asax methods to inspect the request before it loads the page e.g. Application_BeginRequest(). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) for information about these events.